# how do i put a space between my image and its border?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a space between my image and it's border.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Padding](http://w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) in your style attribute or CSS class.

Answer (score 5):

*Padding* allows you to control the space between your image and its border. Padding is just one piece of a larger concept, the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_boxmodel.asp), which includes the content, padding, border and margin. I encourage you to check it out!

The CSS required in your case would be of the form:

`<img src="foo.jpg" style="padding:10px;" />`

Answer (score 1):

Use padding

```
#image {border-right: 1px solid #000; padding-right: 10px;}
```